# restrict UIPanGestureRecognizer in UIView Mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am masking UIView(240 * 240) in tringular shape using **UIBezierPath** as follows:

```
path = [UIBezierPath new];
[path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 240}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){120,0}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){240,240}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){0,240}];
[path closePath];

CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
mask.frame = self.viewShape.bounds;
mask.path = path.CGPath;
self.viewShape.layer.mask = mask;
```

[image]

In above Image triangular area is mask. Now I have image of "Coca-Cola" which is to be moved only in triangular mask. So, for that I have apply **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to **UIIMageView** and restrict its frame in following way.

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.viewShape];

    CGRect boundsRect;

    BOOL isInside = [path containsPoint:CGPointMake(self.innerView.center.x, self.innerView.center.y)];
    NSLog(@"value:%d",isInside);
    if (isInside) {
        NSLog(@"inside");
        self.innerView.center = touchLocation;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"outside");
    }
}
```

My above **if** condition executes successfully but when control goes into **else** condition I am not able to drag back my ImageView inside mask frame.

So, My question is when **else** block(outside) called I should be able to drag imageView again inside the Mask's frame.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified some portion of Meth's code. The code is as follows:

```
self.innerView.center = touchLocation;
BOOL isInside = [path containsPoint:CGPointMake(self.innerView.center.x, self.innerView.center.y)];
if (isInside) {
        NSLog(@"inside");
        self.innerView.center = touchLocation;
        lastValidCenter = self.innerView.center;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"outside");
        self.innerView.center = lastValidCenter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

saving reference to last center of imageview is a way to achieve this.
in your customView;

```
CGPoint lastValidCenter; //initially it is the center of imageview;
```

and in the code

```
NSLog(@"value:%d",isInside);
    if (isInside) {
        NSLog(@"inside");
        self.innerView.center = touchLocation;
        lastValidCenter = self.innerView.center;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"outside");
        self.innerView.center = lastValidCenter;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had done such kind of implementation but got same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your calculation. What you need to do is to check the top-left and top-right corner of the `UIImageView` for contains point with `UIBezirePath` instance.
It is so because when the image will move both of these corners are the ones which will try to go out first. So just put a check and you'll get your desired output.

```
BOOL isInside = [path containsPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.innerView.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.innerView.bounds))];
isInside = isInside || [path containsPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.innerView.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.innerView.bounds))];
if (isInside) {
//Move your UIImageView
}
else {
//Don't move
}
```